# How to remove ~ from mod_userdir link?

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel, whm, mod-userdir

I have centos7 dedi with latest whm/cpanel install I've enabled access to user dirs without domains example http://ip/~user but my target is to be http://ip/user

Now my question would be is it possible to remove ~ and how...?
Googled a lot and read a lot but didn't found answer...

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\/([^~\/]+?(?:\/.*|$)) /~$1 [L]
```

**Warning**: the above will rewrite every url to ~url regardless of if the user exists, so if you go to `http://IP/exampleurl` it will rewrite that to `http://IP/~exampleurl`, It only checks if a file or a directory exists there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, tried reversed rule to remove ~ but doesn't work on latest whm/cpanel

Answer (score 0):

You really should use your hosts file instead of mod_userdir if you're trying to view a site before updating the DNS, or before you have a domain for it.

I can guarantee that mod_userdir will always end up being the unnecessarily difficult solution for this.

This is a guide for using your hosts file instead of mod_userdir:
https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/dns/how-to-modify-your-hosts-file/